Reuse a computed signal in NGRX signal store
In NGRX signal store, I want to reuse the computed value in another computed value that is in withComputed.
For example:
export const ExampleStore = signalStore(
  withState(initialState),
  withComputed(store => ({
    property1: computed(() => store.example()),
    property2: computed(() => store.property1()),
  }))
);

store.property1() is no callable in computed

There are 2 patterns I know of:
Use a second withComputed
export const ExampleStore = signalStore(
  withState(initialState),
  withComputed(store => ({
    property1: computed(() => store.example()),
  })),
  withComputed(store => ({
    property2: computed(() => store.property1()),
  }))
);

In the same withComputed
export const ExampleStore = signalStore(
  withState(initialState),
  withComputed(store => {
    const property1 = computed(() => store.example());
    const property2 = computed(() => property1());
    
    return {property1, property2};
  })
);

